# Jquery simulate click for submit a form don't send value of button

Tags: jquery, button, click, submit

I have a form with two button one for OK action and one for discard action both with a ID and value.
I want to submit the form by jquery click event on button clicked and I need to send a POST to my CMS with name and value of clicked button.
How can I do this?

Comment: `$('#yourForm').submit();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: *"...both with a ID and value..."* *"...I need to send a POST...with name and value..."* Note: `id` != `name`.

Comment: yes but with this cannot also have the name and value of clicked button

Answer (score 0):

The value of (only) the clicked button is anyway sent if the button has a name and is of type submit (default type). Now if you want to attach a click event handler, you still can. And by using `evt.preventDefault()`, you can also cancel the submission.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="index.html" method="POST">
        <button name="action" value="ok">OK</button>
        <button name="action" value="discard">discard</button>
    </form>
    <script>
            document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(evt){
                //return evt.preventDefault();
            });

    </script>        
</body>

</html>
```

Try testing with GET first on a standalone page (e.g. index.html) to see what is sent on the url.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, I have a modal function for alert a message, If I click discard I run jquery click, the form is submited without cencelButton value.

```js
$('input[type=submit]#CancelButton').click();
```

```html
<form action="/layout/set/ajax/content/removeobject" method="post" name="ObjectRemove" id="ObjectRemove">

<div class="warning"><h2>Sei sicuro di voler rimuovere questi elementi?</h2><ul>            <li>Lista delle cose da fare 1 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
  <input type="hidden" name="SupportsMoveToTrash" value="1">
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="MoveToTrash" value="1" checked="checked">Sposta nel cestino</p>

  <p><b>Nota:</b> Se <i>Sposta nel cestino</i> è selezionato troverai gli elementi eliminati nel cestino in seguito.</p>
  <br>

<div class="buttonblock">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="ConfirmButton" id="ConfirmButton" value="Conferma">    
<input class="button" type="submit" id="CancelButton" name="CancelButton" value="Annulla"></div>

</form>
```